# Observables and response data typings

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, asynchronous, observable

I'm trying to get a hang of Observables but sometimes get lost in nothing.

Assume we subscribe to getData to get json data asynchronously:

```
this.getData(id)
    .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(data.items[0])
        // more data processing
    })
```

This works, but processing response data inside .subscribe does not look pleasing. Assigning the response to a var seems like a way to go:

```
let data;
this.getData(id)
        .subscribe(res => data = res)
console.log(data.items[0])
// more data processing
```

But in this case we get error since var 'data' has no initial type.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined

Creating an interface for the json response sounds silly. What am I missing?

Also, creating a callback function seems redundant as well, since it will take 2 functions to do the work of what supposed to be a single function.

Answer (score 0):

> since var 'data' has no initial type.

No. The error is because *data* is `undefined`. TypeScript is smart enough to see that `data` isn't initialized https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/javascript/recap.html. The order in which the code executes is given below:

```
let data; // 1 
this.getData(id)
        .subscribe(res => data = res) // 3!
console.log(data.items[0]) // 2
```

## More

Please lookup async programming in JavaScript / TypeScript. Basically you can only use data once `subscribe` is called.

Comment: okay, I understand that. How should I structure it then where I would need to process the data from multiple observables, if that makes sense..?

Comment: You can use these operations : https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Combining-Observables < java docs , but javascript rxjs has same operations

Comment: so what's the advantage of using observables and not just a callback with anonymous function? `func(_, {})`